# ASP.net disable post processing

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to print some json encoded strings that contains URLs but the server keeps "correcting" them.

Here are some examples of what the server is doing:

```
Response.Write("<a href=\\\"http://www.google.com\\\">asdf</a>");
Response.Write("<a \"http://www.google.com\">asdf</a>");
```

Results in:

```
<a href="\"http://www.google.com\"">asdasd</a>
<a>asdasd</a>
```

How can I stop the server from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever it was that messed with my response stopped after adding

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

to the code.

Answer (score 0):

[HtmlEncode?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This more of a workaround since you will need to do additional javascript hax to decode it later. The text will be put in an textarea for edit so I need the tags to be unencoded.